# Find permutation of one string into other string program

Tags: c#, algorithm, anagram, sliding-window

Trying to make an program where it just check, if permutation of `string` `s1` exists in `string` `s2` or not.

Created below program and it works for below test case.

Input:

```
s1 = "ab"
s2 = "eidballl"
```

Output:

`True`

Explanation: `s2` contains one permutation of `s1` (that is `ba`).

But this get fail when, input `s2="sdfdadddbd"` , `s1="ab"`, **expected** as, `false`, but **got** `true`.

I'm trying to figure out what is missing here. Using a sliding window approach. Below my code in `c#`:

```cs
   public bool CheckInclusion(string s1, string s2) {

        var intCharArray = new int[256];

        foreach(char c in s1)
        {
            intCharArray[c]++;
        }

        int start=0,end=0;
        int count=s1.Length;
        bool found=false;
        while(end<s2.Length)
        {
            if (intCharArray[s2[end]]>0) { count--;}
            intCharArray[s2[end]]--;


                Console.WriteLine("end:" + end + " start:"+ start);
                if(end-start==s1.Length) {

                    if (count==0) {return true;}
                    if (intCharArray[s2[start]]>=0)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    intCharArray[s2[start]]++;
                    start++;
                }
                    end++;
            }
        return false;
        }
```

Comment: There’s no place where the code returns anything else than `true`, so it can’t ever say `false` regardless of the algorithm

Comment: Edited with false.

Comment: Rethink what Sami said, ok? Changing it to false will not solve the fact that there's just a single `return` there with a hardcoded returned value. How do you want it to decide whever the answer is YES/NO when it always returns YES or always returns NO?

Comment: Edited part is like this, `if(end-start==s1.Length) {return true;}` and `return false` if it was never found true.   Posted an question to figure out the issue where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the question is similar to [LeetCode 567](https://leetcode.com/problems/permutation-in-string/). These are simple, efficient, low-complexity accepted solutions:

**C#**

```
class Solution {
    public bool CheckInclusion(string s1, string s2) {
        int lengthS1 = s1.Length;
        int lengthS2 = s2.Length;

        if (lengthS1 > lengthS2)
            return false;

        int[] countmap = new int[26];

        for (int i = 0; i < lengthS1; i++)
            countmap[s1[i] - 97]++;


        int[] bCount = new int[26];

        for (int i = 0; i < lengthS2; i++) {
            bCount[s2[i] - 97]++;

            if (i >= (lengthS1 - 1)) {
                if (allZero(countmap, bCount))
                    return true;

                bCount[s2[i - (lengthS1 - 1)] - 97]--;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    private bool allZero(int[] s1, int[] s2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            if (s1[i] != s2[i])
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

#### Java

```
class Solution {
    public boolean checkInclusion(String s1, String s2) {
        int lengthS1 = s1.length();
        int lengthS2 = s2.length();

        if (lengthS1 > lengthS2)
            return false;

        int[] countmap = new int[26];

        for (int i = 0; i < lengthS1; i++) {
            countmap[s1.charAt(i) - 97]++;
            countmap[s2.charAt(i) - 97]--;
        }

        if (allZero(countmap))
            return true;

        for (int i = lengthS1; i < lengthS2; i++) {
            countmap[s2.charAt(i) - 97]--;
            countmap[s2.charAt(i - lengthS1) - 97]++;

            if (allZero(countmap))
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    private boolean allZero(int[] count) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            if (count[i] != 0)
                return false;

        return true;
    }
}
```

#### Python

```
class Solution:
    def checkInclusion(self, s1, s2):
        count_map_s1 = collections.Counter(s1)
        count_map_s2 = collections.Counter(s2[:len(s1)])

        for i in range(len(s1), len(s2)):
            if count_map_s1 == count_map_s2:
                return True

            count_map_s2[s2[i]] += 1
            count_map_s2[s2[i - len(s1)]] -= 1
            if count_map_s2[s2[i - len(s1)]] == 0:
                del(count_map_s2[s2[i - len(s1)]])

        return count_map_s2 == count_map_a
```

#### Reference

The codes are explained in the following links:

- [LeetCode 567 Solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/permutation-in-string/solution/)
- [LeetCode 567 Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/permutation-in-string/discuss/?currentPage=1&orderBy=most_posts&query=)

---

These two answers are also useful to look into:

- [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62323844/6553328)
- [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62310241/6553328)

Comment: Thanks for the info. this way it worked. I have edited code block in description. I was thinking, it could be work through this piece of block when reaches to `window length` and `count==0` so match found but its not work. Full code block updated on description above, `if(end-start==s1.Length) {

                    if (count==0) {return true;}
                    if (intCharArray[s2[start]]>=0)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    intCharArray[s2[start]]++;
                    start++;
                }`

Answer (score 3):

you need to check all characters of permutation exist in any range of [i, i + p.Length) of the string

```
static class StringExtensions
{
    public static bool ContainsAnyPermutationOf(this string str, string p)
    {
        Dictionary<char, int> chars_count = p.CreateChar_CountDictionary();

        for (int i = 0; i <= str.Length - p.Length; i++)
        {
            string subString = str.Substring(i, p.Length);
            if (DictionaryMatch(chars_count, subString.CreateChar_CountDictionary()))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private static bool DictionaryMatch(Dictionary<char, int> dictionary1, Dictionary<char, int> dictionary2)
    {
        if (dictionary1.Count != dictionary2.Count)
        {
            return false;
        }
        foreach (var kvp in dictionary1)
        {
            if (!dictionary2.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
            {
                return false;
            }
            dictionary2[kvp.Key] = dictionary2[kvp.Key] - 1;
            if (dictionary2[kvp.Key] == 0)
            {
                dictionary2.Remove(kvp.Key);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private static Dictionary<char, int> CreateChar_CountDictionary(this string str)
    {
        Dictionary<char, int> dic = new Dictionary<char, int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!dic.ContainsKey(str[i]))
            {
                dic.Add(str[i], default);
            }
            dic[str[i]] = dic[str[i]] + 1;
        }
        return dic;
    }
}
```

usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("sdfdadddbd".ContainsAnyPermutationOf("ab"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```cs
private static bool CheckPermutationInclusion(string s1, string s2)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, s2.Length - s1.Length)
                     .Select(i => s2.Substring(i, s1.Length))
                     .Any(x => x.All(y => s1.Contains(y)));
}
```

Description:

- [`Enumerable.Range(Int32, Int32)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netcore-3.1) Method: Generates a sequence of integral numbers within a specified range.
- [`Enumerable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1) Method: Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.
- [`Enumerable.All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netcore-3.1) Method: Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.
- [`Enumerable.Any`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netcore-3.1) Method: Determines whether any element of a sequence exists or satisfies a condition.

Do not forget `using System.Linq;`.